# java string replace best way to do

Tags: java, string

I have a String:

```
a0 + a1*ln(Hr) + a2*ln(St) + a3*ln(Tr)
```

This need to be converted in to:

```
a1 + a2*log(Hr[i]) + a3*log(St[i]) + a4*log(Tr[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String f = "a0 + a1*ln(Hr) + a2*ln(St) + a3*ln(Tr)";
f.replaceAll("ln", "log").replaceAll("\\(([A-Z][a-z])\\)","($1[i])"));
```

This will replace all `ln` by `log` and will add `[i]` after each `(Xx)` string.

Comment: thanqu very much for you reply.. its working but one more change.. if you observe my conversion issue.. in first string it is a0 + a1*ln(Hr) and after converstion it must be a1 + a2*log(Hr[i])

Comment: I hope you meant `f.replaceAll................`

Comment: @Tapsi it's a little more evolved then, you need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` to iterate trough the matches and increment the `x#` strings. Take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

I would use replaceAll() if you only have this string.

If you need to apply the pattern more often think about using [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)